# Understand this (missing) solution for leetcode 53. Maximum Subarray

Tags: algorithm, go

For the solution to leetcode problem 53. Maximum Subarray, the most comprehensive answers I can find is [here](https://github.com/azl397985856/leetcode/blob/master/problems/53.maximum-sum-subarray-en.md), in which it lists & explains 4 different approaches to solve the problem.

The following solution, which I haven't found a good explanation yet,

```golang
func maxSubArray(nums []int) int {
    if len(nums) == 1 {
        return nums[0]
    }
    maxSum, res, p := nums[0], 0, 0
    for p < len(nums) {
        res += nums[p]
        if res > maxSum {
            maxSum = res
        }
        if res < 0 {
            res = 0
        }
        p++
    }
    return maxSum
}
```

looks too simple to be working, yet it solve the problem just fine.

Anyone can see how it is working please? Especially, why the check `if res < 0 { res = 0 }` is needed and what does it mean?

Comment: Have you checked [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)?

Comment: That explains it. Thanks @MBo. I was using leetcode as KW in my search and had never thought that there is a wiki page to the leetcode problem.

Answer (score -1):

`if res < 0 { res = 0 }` is needed because nums[p] could be a negative integer hence res could be negative, so to achieve maximum subarray sum, it is better to add the nums[p+1] to a 0 rather than a negative integer. That's why `res` is reset to 0 for next iteration.

lets say: res = -2, and nums[p+1] = 4, it would be better to add 4 to 0 than to add 4 to a -2.

Hope I am able to make things a bit clear.